# Windows Spotlight option is missing. How can I enable it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, spotlight

It's my personal computer running Fall Creators Update. Not connected to any Office or College network. I am not sure why I am seeing "Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization" message. Is that the clue to missing Windows Spotlight feature? Help please

[image]

Comment: This is Windows Pro Education which is Windows Pro + Education features. Windows 10 Education and Windows 10 Pro Education are different. Are you sure Spotlight isn't there in Windows 10 Pro Education as well?

Comment: Is there any Microsoft page/link which clarifies on this? From what I read online Windows 10 Pro Education is Windows 10 Pro + Education. It is supposed to have all the features of Pro. Is that wrong?